# Problems sharing text with the new Android Studio

Tags: android, text, share

I have a simple app that will, at some point, generate a string of text that I want to share with any other app installed on the phone that can take a string of text (twitter, facebook, etc.)
Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
   sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
   sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
   startActivity(sendIntent);
```

This is from: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-text-content

However, Android studio says it "cannot resolve" startActivity and suggests that I do this:

```
import static android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivity;
```

Ok, so I do that and now startActivity() is expecting three inputs. This seems to be a new requirement because of an update. All the code examples I've seen only give it two inputs at most. The expectation is:

1. An activity???
2. The intent, which we defined
3. The bundle/extra options which I am leaving null

How do I satisfy the first input? Will it be possible to redirect back to my app after the sharing function is complete?

Comment: Okay, big take away for anyone trying to do this. You have to implement this in the Main.java. The one that extends "Activity" If you try call this in a subroutine (i.e. a click event in another .java class) it won't cooperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is the title");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

setting title is not compulsory. then the "share using" is just a text which you can replace with anything you want. its just shows above all suggested application